# How to use feature image and first post image for thumbnail?

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

To grab and resize thumbnail, I use aqua resizer from this link:

https://github.com/sy4mil/Aqua-Resizer

Call the thumbnail to show with this code on the loop:

```
<?php $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 
$img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumb,'full' ); 
$image = aq_resize( $img_url, 150, 700, true ); 
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image ?>" width="150" height="700" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
```

It is working well. But only for feature image.
I want to set the caller not for feature image, but also for first post image.
So when I forget to set feature image on my post, the first image will show up as the thumbnail.

I know the code flow should be like this:

```
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
// resize post thumbnail here e.g. $img_url = aq_resize...
} elseif($first_img) {
// resize the first img here, $img_url = aq_resize($first_img, ...
} else {
// $img_url = ''; //empty
}
```

But I'm new on php. Can anybody help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "The first post image" as in the first image added via the editor?

Answer (score 2):

You could put this function in your functions.php, and then call it from anywhere. It will return the source attribute of the first image tag it finds in your post, or a blank string if it doesn't find anything.

```
function get_first_image_src()
{
    $content = get_the_content();
    $image_regex = "/<img [^>]*src=[\"']([^\"^']*)[\"']/";
    preg_match($image_regex, $content, $match);

    if (empty($match))
        return "";

    return $match[1];
}
```